# How to prevent multiple windows?

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that generates a second window when a button is clicked, and need to prevent additional clicks to that button generating multiple simultaneous windows.  Using an if statement comparing the variable to null isn't working, even when reapplying the value null directly to the variable.

Comment: it might be beneficial to show some code for this.

Answer (score 2):

The most intuitive thing from the user perspective seems to be that the button be disabled once it is clicked. Otherwise you could easily have a boolean that you set/check when the button is clicked.

Comment: Either that, or make the window modal.  Once the window is displayed, its parent component can't be interacted with.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this, by checking if the new Window is visible already or not by using isShowing(), which will return true/false, and you can do the newWindow.setVisible(true), only if isShowing() returned false, inside the actionPerformed() method of your JButton. Every Component has this method [Component.isShowing()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

add `button.setVisible(false);` 
 Your button will not be visible then, You can set button visible again when you need to perform some action on it.